# Olecontroller not showing in grid

Tags: foxpro, visual-foxpro

I want to show Chinese characters in my form.  Somehow I am able to do this by using `activex controller forms.text.2`

But when I replace the textbox in a grid with my olecontroller, it won't show up during runtime. I need to select or setfocus the column first - just to show it.

The `sparse` property of the column is already `.F.` and the setcontroller is my olecontroller.
I don't know what to do anymore, does anyone have an idea on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Open your form, then open the properties sheet.  Click on the grid. Then from the properties sheet, scroll down to the COLUMN having your activeX control.  Then look at the property "CurrentControl" of the column.  It probably has a combobox of the default "Text1" textbox control AND another for your ActiveX control.  Change the currentControl to that of your activeX control, save and run.